# Cannot complete Google Drive authentication in exe file

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pyinstaller

I have a python program that requires Google Drive Authentication. When I run it in Windows from  the command Line

```
python xxx.py
```

it works perfectly.

I have created an exe file using pyi-build (PyInstaller). When I double click on the exe file it takes me to the authentication page. I click on 'Allow' and I get the exception 'Google Drive not authenticated'

The relevant code follows

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
try:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
except:
    dlg=wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Google Drive not authenticated', 'xxxxx', wx.OK|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
    result=dlg.ShowModal()
    self.Close()
```

EDIT:
I have modified the code following the suggestion by android below

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
try:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
except Exception as e:
    dlg=wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Google Drive not authenticated'+repr(e), 'xxxxx', wx.OK|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
    result=dlg.ShowModal()
    self.Close()
```

Unfortunately it now crashes without even showing the dialog.

So I tried

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
try:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
except Exception as e:
    logging.debug(repr(e))
    dlg=wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Google Drive not authenticated', 'xxxxx', wx.OK|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
    result=dlg.ShowModal()
    self.Close()
```

and again it crashes with an empty log file.

Can anyone suggest what is amiss or a workaround?

Comment: You're using a "bare except" which means it's catching **all exceptions**. Which should generally _never_ be used. At the very least, what you should do now is `except Exception as e` which is almost as bad as a "bare except", except you can print/output/log the caught exception `e` and that will be the _first step_ to figuring out the cause of the problem. And afterwards, modify your code to only handle that exception while others are propagated up, and caught if required (with an output to you/users).

Comment: Thanks aneroid. I'll try it later